# Segmentation fault from a function that is not called at all

Tags: c, linux, function, gcc, segmentation-fault

Ok, this is really freaking me out. I have a following function that just reads input and returns a string

```
unsigned char* readFromIn() {
    unsigned char* text = malloc(1024);
    if (fgets(text, 1024, stdin) != NULL) {          <--This is what's causing segmentation fault
        int textLen = strlen(text);
        if (textLen > 0 && text[textLen - 1] == '\n')
            text[textLen - 1] = '\0';     // getting rid of newline character
        return text;
    }
    else {
        free(text);
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

The thing is, this function isn't called anywhere and just to confirm, I changed the name of the function to something crazy like 9rawiohawr90awrhiokawrioawr and put printf statement on the top of the function.

I'm genuinely not sure why an uncalled function might cause a segmentation fault error.

I'm using gcc 4.6.3 on ubuntu.

Edit: I know that the line

```
if (fgets(text, 1024, stdin) != NULL) {
```

is the offending code because as soon as i comment out that conditional, no segmentation error occurs.

I know that the function is **NOT** being called because i'm seeing no output of the printf debug statement I put.

Edit2: I've tried changing the type from unsigned char to char. Still segmentation error. I will try to get gdb output.

Edit3: gdb backtrace produced the following

```
#0 0xb7fa5ac2 in _IO_2_1_stdin_ () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#1 0xb7faf2fb in libwebsocket_create_context (info=0xbffff280) at libwebsockets.c:2125
#2 0x0804a5bb in main()
```

doing frame 0,1,2 doesn't output anything interesting in particular.

Edit4: I've tried all of the suggestions in the comment, but to no avail, I still get the same segmentation fault.

So I installed a fresh copy of Ubuntu on a virtual OS and recompiled my code. **Still the same issue occurs.** 
It seems to me the problem is in either some obscurity going on in my code or the library itself. I've created a minimal example demonstrating the problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <libwebsockets.h>


unsigned char* readFromIn() {
    unsigned char* text = malloc(1024);
    if (fgets(text, 1024, stdin) != NULL) { <--SEGMENTATION FAULT HERE
        int textLen = strlen(text);
        if (textLen > 0 && text[textLen - 1] == '\n')
            text[textLen - 1] = '\0';    
        return text;
    }
    else {
        free(text);
        return NULL;
    }
}

int callback_http(struct libwebsocket_context *context,
                         struct libwebsocket *wsi,
                         enum libwebsocket_callback_reasons reason, void *user,
                         void *in, size_t len)
{
    return 0;
}

static struct libwebsocket_protocols protocols[] = {
    /* first protocol must always be HTTP handler */
    {
        "http-only",   // name
        callback_http, // callback
        0              // per_session_data_size
    }
};

int main(void) {
    printf("Initializing Web Server\n");
        // server url will be http://localhost:8081
    int port = 8081;
    const char *interface = NULL;
    struct libwebsocket_context *context;
    // we're not using ssl
    const char *cert_path = NULL;
    const char *key_path = NULL;
    // no special options
    int opts = 0;


    struct lws_context_creation_info info;

    memset(&info, 0, sizeof info);
    info.port = port;
    info.iface = interface;
    info.protocols = protocols;
    info.extensions = libwebsocket_get_internal_extensions();
    info.ssl_cert_filepath = NULL;
    info.ssl_private_key_filepath = NULL;
    info.gid = -1;
    info.uid = -1;
    info.options = opts;

    context = libwebsocket_create_context(&info);
    if (context == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "libwebsocket init failed\n");
        return 0;
    }

    printf("starting server...\n");

    while (1) {
        libwebsocket_service(context, 50);
    }
    printf("Shutting server down...\n");
    libwebsocket_context_destroy(context);

    return 0;
}
```

And here's how I compiled my code

```
gcc -g testbug.c -o test -lwebsockets
```

Here's the library I'm using

http://git.libwebsockets.org/cgi-bin/cgit/libwebsockets/tag/?id=v1.23-chrome32-firefox24

You will see that I'm not calling the function readFromIn() yet, segmentation fault occurs as soon as you try to run the executable.

I've re-ran gdb and this time, backtrace and the frames tell me a little bit more info.

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/l46kok/Desktop/websocketserver/test 
Initializing Web Server
[1384002761:2270] NOTICE: Initial logging level 7
[1384002761:2270] NOTICE: Library version: 1.3 unknown-build-hash
[1384002761:2271] NOTICE:  Started with daemon pid 0
[1384002761:2271] NOTICE:  static allocation: 4448 + (12 x 1024 fds) = 16736 bytes
[1384002761:2271] NOTICE:  canonical_hostname = ubuntu
[1384002761:2271] NOTICE:  Compiled with OpenSSL support
[1384002761:2271] NOTICE:  Using non-SSL mode
[1384002761:2271] NOTICE:  per-conn mem: 124 + 1360 headers + protocol rx buf
[1384002761:2294] NOTICE:  Listening on port 8081

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0xb7fb1ac0 in _IO_2_1_stdin_ () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
(gdb) backtrace
#0  0xb7fb1ac0 in _IO_2_1_stdin_ () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#1  0xb7fcc2c6 in libwebsocket_create_context () from /usr/local/lib/libwebsockets.so.4.0.0
#2  0x080488c4 in main () at testbug.c:483
(gdb) frame 1
#1  0xb7fcc2c6 in libwebsocket_create_context () from /usr/local/lib/libwebsockets.so.4.0.0
(gdb) frame 2
#2  0x080488c4 in main () at testbug.c:483
483         context = libwebsocket_create_context(&info);
```

So yeah.. I think I gave all the information at hand.. but I'm genuinely not sure what the issue is. The program causes segmentation fault at line 483 but the issue is gone when I comment out the offending function that's not being called.

Comment: Did you try `make clean; make`?

Comment: And you know it's being called, because you're seeing output from the `printf`? It would probably help if we could see more of the relevant code.

Comment: Build with debug information, and run in a debugger. It will stop at the crash, and you will be able to see the function call stack. And if the call-stack looks "weird" (please edit your question to include it), then it's likely you have a stack-smashing problem.

Comment: Referring "edit3:": Which code do you find at `libwebsockets.c:2125`?

Comment: People are possibly jumping the gun a bit here.  You say that this function is never called?  Then I would consider the idea that your stack is being corrupted with a bit of good old Undefined Behaviour that started somewhere else.

Comment: @alk Blank line. See https://github.com/warmcat/libwebsockets/blob/master/lib/libwebsockets.c

Comment: @paddy I don't understand though, the whole program runs fine without that function (at least no observable errors). How do I find out undefined behaviors you're speaking of?

Comment: @l46kok Maybe use Valgrind

Comment: Also compile with a recent GCC (e.g. 4.8) using both `-Wall -g` and `-fsanitize=`*something* ....

Comment: Also put a breakpoint in your function with gdb and make sure you actually reach that point. `printf` are no good just before segfaults ; if the buffer is not flushed in time you won't see any output even thought printf was called.

Comment: "*Blank line*": Then obviously the objects **aren't in sync** with the sources! Have a sleep, get up, have a coffee, clean-up and rebuild.

Comment: Just try this function along with main() , and run it separately without using *makefiles* ,as a separate C program, you will get an idea about what @alk is saying.

Comment: what's `callback_http`?

Comment: It seems to me from the description of the problem that you've accidentally created a ['return to library'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return-to-libc_attack) stack overflow problem that happens to write the return address of the function that you don't think you call over the return address that is on the stack. This simulates calling your function, and havoc ensues (especially if the return address isn't the actual start of the function).  It is a technique used to exploit stack and heap overflows. It is incredibly sensitive to the linking order and the size of the functions and so on.

Comment: Can you post the code somewhere where we can try to build and recreate it ?

Comment: @stdcall Please see edit 4. I've posted a fully working minimized version of the code that reproduces my problem.

Comment: The function is likely called but you don't see the printf because printf is buffered and the program segfault before the stdout buffer is flushed. Try fprintf on stderr (which is not buffered)

Comment: Your SSCCE compiles and runs for me. What versions of GCC and libwebsockets do you have?

Comment: And for the record, I agree with Jonathan Leffler, it's probably a stack overflow elsewhere.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Probably you're missing something when initializing libwebsockets.

Indeed, recompiling libwebsockets with debug reveals that:

```
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.6.1 (Debian 7.6.1-1)
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>...
Reading symbols from /home/vili/x...done.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/vili/./x
warning: Could not load shared library symbols for linux-vdso.so.1.
Do you need "set solib-search-path" or "set sysroot"?
Initializing Web Server
[1384020141:5692] NOTICE: Initial logging level 7
[1384020141:5692] NOTICE: Library version: 1.2
[1384020141:5693] NOTICE:  Started with daemon pid 0
[1384020141:5693] NOTICE:  static allocation: 5512 + (16 x 1024 fds) = 21896 bytes
[1384020141:5693] NOTICE:  canonical_hostname = x220
[1384020141:5693] NOTICE:  Compiled with OpenSSL support
[1384020141:5693] NOTICE:  Using non-SSL mode
[1384020141:5693] NOTICE:  per-conn mem: 248 + 1328 headers + protocol rx buf
[1384020141:5713] NOTICE:  Listening on port 8081

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7bc2080 in _IO_2_1_stderr_ () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff7bc2080 in _IO_2_1_stderr_ () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007ffff7bcd83c in libwebsocket_create_context (info=0x7fffffffe580)
    at libwebsockets.c:2093
#2  0x0000000000400918 in main () at x.c:66
(gdb) up
#1  0x00007ffff7bcd83c in libwebsocket_create_context (info=0x7fffffffe580)
    at libwebsockets.c:2093
2093                    info->protocols[context->count_protocols].callback(context,
(gdb) p context->count_protocols
$1 = 1
(gdb) p info->protocols[1]
$2 = {
  name = 0x7ffff7bc2240 <_IO_2_1_stdin_> "\210 \255", <incomplete sequence \373>, callback = 0x7ffff7bc2080 <_IO_2_1_stderr_>,
  per_session_data_size = 140737349689696, rx_buffer_size = 0,
  owning_server = 0x602010, protocol_index = 1}
(gdb)
```

Quite likely you need to close the array of `libwebsocket_protocols` with a special entry (NULL) so that the lib will know how many entries it got via info->protocols.

Edit: yep, check the docs: http://jsk.pp.ua/knowledge/libwebsocket.html

> Array of structures listing supported protocols and a protocol- specific callback for each one. The list is ended with an entry that
>   has a NULL callback pointer.

Comment: Absolutely unbelievable, I can't believe I got bitten nastily by forgetting something like that! Guess that's the price you pay for not carefully reading the documentation. Many thanks!

Comment: Happens with everyone... In cases like this, don't be afraid of diving into the library where the problem seems to happen.